# Is it possible for a desktop application to get the website URL?

Tags: .net, web, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application which has to notify the user if antivirus or other security software are disabled once the user opens a bank wabsite.The bank website url 
is known for the application. My application has to fire a notification window if the given bank site is going to be accessed from the user.I want the application to check which site (link) is opening by the user and if it is the predefined link the notification form should appear. Is something like this possible to be done without developing browser add-ins?

Comment: +1 this might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2341199/How-to-detect-browser-url-using-vb-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

The longer answer is Yes. But you'd have to go into either network sniffing (won't work - bank traffic is usually encrypted) or memory stuff (manually reading strings from the RAM, etc). In both cases it's at least 1000x easier to make a browser add-in.

Comment: I can not imagine how both answers could exists in the same time, I mean YES/NO. True only the one!

Comment: If you're a very good programmer, yes. Otherwise, no. Judging by the fact that he/she had to ask I'd go with No.

Comment: it does not mean if one is a very good programmer should know every  thing

Comment: If one is a good enough programmer to be able to work with raw encrypted SSL streams and reading the keys from the memory, one will come up with the idea him/herself. (source: experience)

Comment: Yes I came up with that Idea ,but i needed some opinions about the best solution

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by developing either browser-add-in and/or a http(s)-proxy and/or sandboxing the browser and/or replacing the browser with a modified version and/or hacking the browser...

IF you really just want to do it with a normal desktop application it is thinkable (polling the browser for currently open URLs) BUT I would strongly recommend to not do this... it would not work reliably and it would put some strain on the resources...

If I had to implement this I would definitely write a browser-add-in and/or a http(s) proxy... any reason why you exclude a browser-add-in for this ?

Comment: by polling the browser do you mean developing an add-in which polls the browser?

Comment: @Tady no - I mean a desktop application which polls (= periodically asks) the browser (for example IE via COM).

Comment: @Tady BTW you can build a proxy and host it in a desktop app or Windows Service... main point with a proxy is that the browser/OS must be configured to use it...

Comment: I would preferr to not use add-ins as many users are disturbed from add-ins

Comment: @Tady I think users are more distrubed with desktop applications behaving as a proxy or polling the browser which is even worse... IF it is a proxy then let the use know, and if it is an add-in then let the user know what it does etc. - and if someone does not want any of these then there is not much you should do about it!

Answer (score 0):

hypothetically, if your application acted as an HTTP Proxy for the user's browser, then yes.. you could intercept the request for the Bank Website and respond with your recommendations to the user..

Comment: Does it require too much work to add a HTTP Proxy functionality to the desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. (At least without much work and/or manual configuration on every computer)

You have a lot of problems to solve:

1. How are you going to get "the url" from "the browser"?
2. What about security?
3. How should you determine if the antivirus or firewall is enabled?

Let's divide an "url" into smaller pieces (lets limit us to the http-protocol):

HTTP is an TCP/IP-connection between two IP-addresses and two ports, the server normally responds on port 80 (if you omit the port the default is 80). Example url:

http://123.123.123.123:456 (connect with http to ip 123.123.123.123 on port 456)

Then we have dns; a domain name will be translated to an ip-adress, example:

http://foobar.com => http://123.123.123.123 (dns translated foobar.com to 123.123.123.123)

Now, assume you add a path to your url, example:

http://foobar.com/path/to/page.htm

What do we do now? There's no such thing as a "path" in TCP/IP. It's on the HTTP level. Let's take a look on a very basic http-url and it's translation to a TCP/IP-connection:

http://foobar.com/path/to/page.htm =>

1. Client looks up foobar.com => 123.123.123.123
2. Client connects to 123.123.123.123 on port 80
3. Client sends the following data to the server:

```
GET /path/to/page.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: foobar.com
```

How are you going to get your hands on the tcp/ip-connections (and their "contents")?

You have a few choices:

- A filter (installed into the networking layer. Sensitive stuff, all I've tried has caused instability and performance loss, apart from trouble - firewalls..)
- A proxy (you have to make sure that every browser has redirected their network traffic through your proxy - there's no global setting, every browser has their own way)
- Some kind of plugin for the browser (you have to write a new plugin for every browser, and make sure it's enabled)

Let's look a security - in case HTTPS (HTTP with SSL) is used then another problem is introduced: the content of every network connection is encrypted, and you can't decrypt it unless you have the key (and you haven't, unless you provide your own, but then the browser won't trust your key and issue a big warning, unless you've installed your key in the browser. And you don't want to do that - it's a fairly big security risk..)

Let's imagine you've solved this problem, how are you going to know whether an anti virus is installed and enabled? And a firewall? Every anti virus and firewall has their own way.

Comment: regarding to antiviruses it can be done using WMI .this is not difficult.

Comment: I do not need to translate from urls or links as I know the link is predefined www.mybank.com and this link is a constant in my application,but anyway thank you for the long reply

Comment: Do you know exactly which ip-addresses you should be looking for? (A dns query might give you one ip, the next might give you another..) And it's not that easy to just query WMI - I wouldn't count on that every antivirus and firewall software has bothered with that

Comment: I had done already the part regarding to antiviruses.some ppl use only one namespace of WMI and why they have problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your .Net desktop application is used to show a notification when a user hits your predefined banking website. Then given the effort required with the alternate answers, from experience (in finance) wouldn't make more sense to make your application launch the link. Then you could do your checks, show the notification and if you launched the website with a unique querystring parameter generated from the desktop application, users browsing the website would have an extra layer of security.

If users dont have your application installed, wont that defeat the point of doing all these checks (to notify the user if antivirus or other security software are disabled once the user opens a bank website) in the first place.