# writing browser plug-in in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I wrote a desktop application in c# with Visual Studio 2008 and I want it to communicate with browser following this scenario: once a user opens a bank website an event should be sent to the desktop application.The link of bank is predifined (known).In other words I want to develp a browser plugin which fires events to the application if users opens the link.
At this stage I want just for one of the browsers Mozilla or IE9.
Any idea or tutorial how to start developing such a plug-in?

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? sounds shady.

Comment: you can have a look at my other relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282092/is-it-possible-for-a-desktop-application-to-get-the-website-url

Comment: That is a bad architecture - firing events from a browser plugin to a desktop application! Why not handle whatever needed within the plugin ?

Comment: refer to the answer of following question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions

Comment: refer to the answer of following question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions

Answer (score 1):

Developing an IE 9  Browser Helper Object is relatively easy. Look for "Browser Helper Object". In Firefox you can't develop plug-ins in C#, it has its own extensive plug-in framework. You'll need to freshen up on your JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation,but could you please tell me if there is a way via which from this plugin can send a paramenter to the desktop application.i.e once a specific site(url) is opened from the user the desktop application is runned?